# How often are turbine blades in jet engines replaced?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance, turbine, blade

How often are the turbines in the hot section of the jet engines replaced due to deteriorated TBC? or just how often are they replaced? lets say for CFM56-7

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71091/turbines-in-jet-engines

Comment: You can restrict your question to a specific model of engines as it may vary from engines to engines.

Answer (score 1):

So [this article](https://aviationweek.com/optimizing-engines-through-lifecycle/did-you-know-cfm56-engines-performance-extended-time-wing-advan), says that the average brand new CFM56-7 will go 18,000 cycles (i.e. flights) before its first shop visit.  You can't replace the turbine blade on-wing, only in the overhaul shop.  So we could say that the blades would last at least 18,000 flights, potentially longer.